# Как добавить в коллекцию элемент пользовательского типа - VBA?

Tags: vba, коллекции, типы-данных

У меня стоит задача описать свой тип данных и создать коллекцию такого типа. При попытке добавить в качестве нового элемента коллекции элемент моего типа, компилятор выбрасывает ошибку.

Для примера приведу упрощенный код:

```
Public Type Status
    name As String
End Type

Sub asdf()
    Dim statuses As New Collection
    Dim stas As Status
    stas.name = "STAS" 
    statuses.Add stas 'Место ошибки
End Sub
```

ошибка:

> Compile error:
>   Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions.

Суть в общем-то понимаю. Знаю одно из решений проблемы - использовать class module. К сожалению, такое решение по условию задачи не подходит, так как необходимо описать все новые типы в одном модуле.
Такая же ошибка выбрасывается, когда пытаюсь присвоить элемент своего типа переменной типа Variant. В общем, я в тупике.

Comment: `statuses.Add stas.name`

Comment: В том то и дело, что нужно не название объекта сохранить, а ссылку на него

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, в старых версиях ms office vba отсутствовала возможность помещения пользовательского типа в оболочку Variant. Кажется, что collection использует variant как тип переменной для хранения информационной части списка. Моим решением этой проблемы стало использование массивов данных вместо коллекций. В последних версиях ms office (новее 2016, как минимум), по словам разработчиков, такой проблемы возникнуть не должно. Жаль, что vba так долго к этому шел.